# Add Settings entry for iOS app using Qt 5.4

Tags: c++, ios, qt

I have built an iOS 8.2 app using Qt 5.4.  I want to add a user-entry field in the Settings app like a lot of other apps do, but I can't figure out how to do it. I tried the following (which doesn't work):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

  TDA::TapDisplaySingleton* mainClass =
  new TDA::TapDisplaySingleton(&app);

  QObject::connect(&app, SIGNAL(aboutToQuit()),
               mainClass, SLOT(aboutToQuitApp()));

  QGuiApplication::setOrganizationName("NASA Langley");
  QGuiApplication::setOrganizationDomain("larc.nasa.gov");
  QGuiApplication::setApplicationName("TAP Display");

  QSettings settings;
  settings.setValue("HOSTNAME", "localhost");

  QTimer::singleShot(10, mainClass, SLOT(run()));

  return app.exec();
}
```

When I fire the app up in the Simulator and open the Settings app, my entry does not appear. Does anyone know how to do this effectively in iOS using Qt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, Qt does provide a way to generate a Settings.bundle file for your app.  You need to define a Root.plist and Root.strings file in advance and then add the following to your .PRO file:

```
SETTINGS_BUNDLE_DATA_ROOT.files += Root.plist
SETTINGS_BUNDLE_DATA_ROOT.path = Settings.bundle
SETTINGS_BUNDLE_DATA_LANG.files += Root.strings
SETTINGS_BUNDLE_DATA_LANG.path = Settings.bundle/en.lproj
QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA += SETTINGS_BUNDLE_DATA_ROOT SETTINGS_BUNDLE_DATA_LANG
```

When your project is linked, the bundle will be created.

Answer (score 0):

QSettings is only for storing settings in a persistent fashion. Adding settings to the iOS Settings application is outside of the scope of Qt. Look up "iOS Settings Bundle" for information on how to create those - eg https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html .

Comment: Thanks Hamish.  It seems to me that if Qt is going to claim to be a platform-independent application platform, they will need to abstract this function as well.  Since I am using qmake to generate the xCode project files and NOT putting the resulting files under source control, having to edit the project with every build will not suffice.